# Abused by High-Rep members

Tags: discussion, reputation, closed-questions, down-votes

A couple of days ago, I posted a question on the Game Development Q&A site. It got +6 votes but nobody could answer the question. However, there appeared to be a war of comments below the post, and this war was caused by a high-rep member who happened to hate the question I'd asked. 
Basically, the whole conversation could be summarized by "The high-rep member trying to excuse his hateful comments and all the others trying to defend the question against him." What's more interesting is that the high-rep member even knew that his comments might be considered abusive and kept deleting them after a couple of minutes.
Back then I didn't really care about what was going on in the comment section. I just kept checking the page to see if an answer pops up. After a while, I got disappointed and left; 2 days later I came back to the question, and noticed that it was voted down 9 times, edited down to a point where the friendly tone of my question was removed (even though the question was crystal clear before the edition), and was closed as not constructive. Additionally, all the comments addressing the high-rep member as abusive were removed as well.
Now I understand the "Not Constructive" part (since my question was not really constructive), but the edition and the -9 vote downs makes me feel abused by high-rep members. Additionally, when I tried checking the report on the -9 votes, I noticed that the user was intentionally removed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTIqY.png
Here's the link to the question I'd aksed:  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56689/3d-object-manipulation-framework
The name of the high-rep member who started the comment war is among the people who closed the question. Now again, I have nothing to say against the question being not constructive (hence being closed), but voting it down intentionally and editing when there's no need to sounds unfair to me. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: I can't comment on the rest as I'm not active on Game Development, but that -25 has nothing to do with the downvotes on your post. A user's account was removed; that user had *upvoted* some of your contributions in the past. The reputation that you gained was removed along with the user's votes on your content.

Comment: 4 minutes after posting your question you get 5 upvotes in a couple minutes (which then get reversed the next day). This smells fishy.

Comment: @hammar No votes were reversed in the traditional sense. What happened here was that 5 users who upvoted this post were later deleted.

Comment: @Pekka I agree with the closing of the question, I disagree with voting it down. You don't have to vote down the question in order to be able to vote as 'not constructive' do you?

Comment: @DarrenVortex: "*You don't have to vote down the question in order to be able to vote as 'not constructive' do you?*" No. But it's a crap question. A question so bad that the person asking it (ie: you) *knew* it was a crap question yet asked it anyway. Indeed, you expressed the *hope* that it would be answered before it was closed. So basically you were trying to game the system by crudding up the site with your crap in the hope that someone would grace it with an answer. I have no problem with that question being downvoted.

Comment: No "friendly tone" was removed. Fluff was removed from your question that should not have been there to begin with and would have made it downvote fodder from the very start.

Comment: @DarrenVortex no, it's not necessary to vote down (and I'm not sure whether I would have) - but it's the community's prerogative to vote as it pleases. That's not "abuse".

Comment: @DarrenVortex The question was not closed as "not constructive". It's closed as "not a real question" because it's rather unclear what the actual question is. You have a few screenshots, a description of what you're doing, and (now) a link to a "might be useful" library. What exactly are you having trouble with there?

Comment: @AnnaLear "which lib to use?" is the question, based on the provided situation.

Comment: There are a few points in here (and the answer below that I want to address) You were probably upvoted for your comments against Byte56, the sockpuppets were anti-him in their behavior. Your question was likely downvoted because it was a "which technology to use" question, they are considered off topic here (by meta discussion) and people consider that they are lacking research except for a few long-tail problems.

Comment: Finally, we actually do a bit of the "What should I use" kind of discussions, we just keep them contained to our chatroom. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development stop by sometime.

Comment: Even though this discussion really is over, just wanted to point out 2 things: I was upvoted before any comments addressing byte56, byte56 was the one removing his comments, and byte56 in a private chatroom clearly stated that he was "Trolling". Doesn't matter now anyways. I just think that the rules should change and allow for "What should I use" types of questions because there are wide examples of these questions being asked, favored and answered, yet closed as not a real question or not constructive. But that's not my decision to make...

Comment: Hey @DarrenVortex, sorry this is so confusing for you as a first visit to the site. I can explain again what happened, but I suspect you may know, I wasn't trolling you. Your question was just caught in the cross fire between me legitimately commenting on why I thought it should be closed and another user controlling his sock puppets. The sock puppets were removing my comments, so you couldn't have know the real reason your question was being voted on.

Answer (score 13):

> the edition and the -9 vote downs makes me feel abused by high-rep members.

First, your question does not have -9 downvotes, so I have no idea where you're getting that from. Second, in the recent past, there was a rash of sock-puppetry on GDSE. That's probably where the -25 came from. The sock puppet owner likely upvoted your question from 5 different accounts. [When those sock puppet accounts were removed, the votes were undone, hence the -25.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/31443/darrenvortex?tab=reputation)

Third, your question was edited to remove the "friendly tone" because what you call "friendly tone" is just pointless noise. If you think your question is "not the most 'constructive' question to be asked on a Q&A forum", then you *shouldn't be asking it* to begin with. Indeed, such declarations are basically you showing *disdain* for the rules of GDSE and Stack Exchange as a whole, knowingly posting an inappropriate question.

We don't need introductions and friendly "hello, how are you doing" stuff in questions. We don't need "Any suggestions" stuff at the bottom. To put that in your question at all just makes your question take longer to read, for no real purpose. Just state your question plainly and straightforwardly; if it is reasonable, it will be attended to.

Nothing of *substance* was removed from your question.

Comment: Yes, that's where the -25 came from. I removed a few accounts earlier this week that committed various kinds of vote fraud. I should also note that DarrenVortex's account doesn't look to be at all related to them.

Comment: Interesting, now I understand the vote counts on my question. But why would the sock puppet want to upvote my question?

Comment: I'm against pure, dry, hard questions. When I personally see these, I feel like someone is throwing homework at me, expecting me to do it without a word. I try to be nice when I ask my question so that the other person doesn't feel disrespected. I post 'Thank You' comments and things as such. I think that this is better than a plain old question and there's nothing in GDSE rules that says this is bad or should be removed.

Comment: @DarrenVortex: "*But why would the sock puppet want to upvote my question?*" Because the sock puppet in question was being malicous. You asked a bad question. And upvoting bad questions makes the site worse by making it seem like these are the kinds of questions we want.

Comment: @DarrenVortex: Your question does not exist to get *you* help; it exists to get the *next person* who has that same question as you help. The longer your question is, the longer it takes for that person to realize that your question is the same as his. And thus, the less useful your question is to the "not you" demographic. The goal of an SE site is to create a knowledge-base; we answer questions as a *means* to achieve that goal. Having questions which are clear and direct serves that purpose. Having questions with a lot of irrelevant fluff does not.

Comment: @DarrenVortex: Also, it's been well established on MSO that people can, and will, remove irrelevant material from questions. And that this behavior is perfectly valid.

Comment: If that's the case then you're right, even though I find the longer questions getting more upvotes.

Comment: But why is asking for library / toolkit suggestion considered 'a bad question'? I'm pretty sure that tons of other people find themselves in my shoes, looking for a place to start from but are not sure what tool is suitable for what they want to do, and more experienced developers can help you decide, is that not right?

Comment: @DarrenVortex: "*longer questions getting more upvotes*" There's a difference between a question that gets its length from having meaningful content and a question that's padded with filler.

Comment: @DarrenVortex: "*But why is asking for library / toolkit suggestion considered 'a bad question'?*" Because [Real Questions have Real Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). If every answer is as good as another, if there's no one direct answer, then it's subjective. And since your question is purely a list question (give me a list of things that do X), we don't allow that here.

Comment: No. I didn't ask for a list. I asked for 'the' most suitable framework for what I want to do. Even if I did ask for a list, such questions ("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729416/lightweight-opengl-framework") still get answered and even upvoted, regardless of getting closed (which doesn't make sense), and that's what I was hoping for. On the subject of length, I have to agree with you and thank you for explaining the reasoning to me.

Comment: I mean the fact that they get upvoted, answered and an answer is chosen by the asker means that these are useful questions and Can be answered.

Comment: @DarrenVortex: "*such questions still get answered and even upvoted*" The fact that some people get away with breaking the rules doesn't mean that there *aren't still rules*. Crimes are crimes even if some criminals escape prosecution. We close questions based on objective properties of the question, not based on subjective issues of whether someone *might* find them "useful".

Comment: Well then why are these questions getting closed? They're favored, answered and have real answers. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Even you asked a question like this (and surprisingly this wasn't closed...): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c Maybe this bows down to 'How' I ask the question. If it's clear enough then it's considered ok, i believe.

Comment: I asked another question. I tried to follow your advice, keep it short, be clear and frank, don't ask for a list (even though it seems ok to do so). Let's see how this one goes.

Comment: @DarrenVortex: "*Well then why are these questions getting closed? They're favored, answered and have real answers. What's wrong with that?*" Because they're against the rules. As previously stated. "*Even you asked a question like this (and surprisingly this wasn't closed...):*" I also answered that question almost immediately thereafter. I only posted it because we kept getting repeated questions like that on the C++ tag, and I wanted a single place where that stuff could go.

Comment: @DarrenVortex On SO those type of questions exist usually for the close as duplicate path, instead of having thousands of questions with the same answers repeated.

Comment: @Darrenvortex The discussion on why those questions are closed is had here: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good/700