# I am new to X, ... <actual problem with X>, ... please help, thank you. Edit, flag or what?

Tags: discussion, newbies

I've seen handful of questions beginning with "I am new to X" which is sometimes followed with an actual problem with typos and lack of formatting, then a plea for help and a "thank you". While browsing meta, I found in this question: [Abused by High-Rep members](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1156/abused-by-high-rep-members) that "friendly tone" is not really welcome.

Now, I often see these questions in "review", under first posts. If I edit the question, what should I do with those polite phrases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any edits that get to the point of the question faster is a good one.

Remove openers.

Remove closers.

Make the title of the question the actual question being asked.

Fix spelling/grammar so it's easier to read.